# How to connect different HVAC components each with a blower

Tags: hvac

If there are multiple HVAC components, each has its own blower; for example:

1. Furnace/heater with blower : for heating
2. Air handler with blower : for cooling and dehumidifying, and (optional and if the device supports) heating with electrical heater add-in or reversed heat pump mode (when temperature is not very low).
3. Whole home dehumidifier with blower : for dehumidifying under low temperature when air handler can't be run or the temperature will be lowered. Or when the air handler can't dehumidify to the expected level.
4. Whole home humidifier with blower (there seems to be no such product available) : humidifying during cold dry winter
5. Balanced heat/energy recovering ventilation and air filter with dual blowers : for indoor air quality and energy efficiency

What is the recommended way to use these components together? Can all the components be connected in series? What is the order?

If they are connected in series, should all the blowers always work together (or the blower downstream that is not working could be driven like a wind electric generator and the CFM will be decreased?) and should their specs and working status be always matched?

The ideal picture is all the components except for the ventilator doesn't have its own blower, and all the components without blower are connected in series downstream the fresh air from outside. But existing products all have built-in blowers, then how to use them together?

Comment: Is there no way to add an air conditioning coil to your existing furnace?  Also, most whole-house humidifiers and dehumidifers *don't* have built-in blowers, instead depending on the furnace/AHU/FAU blower for airflow